# S3 Browser Client won't show objects in bucket root folder

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I need to create an IAM policy that restricts access only to the user's folder. I followed the guidelines as specified here:

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html

I also am using this S3 browser since I don't like my users to be using the console: https://s3browser.com/

However, when I tried navigating to the bucket root folder, it gives me an "Access Denied. Would you like to try Requester Pays access?" error.

But if I specify the prefix with the user's folder, I receive no error. Here's the IAM policy I have created:

```
{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AllowRequiredAmazonS3ConsolePermissions",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                    "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "s3:prefix": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "s3:delimiter": [
                            "/"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

The expected result for this IAM policy should allow the user to navigate from the root folder to his/her specific folder.

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that you want to grant permissions for a user to see "their own folder", but not anybody else's folder? If so, the policy will need to have some reference to the user. See: [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `s3:ListBucket` has a condition that it will only allow listing of objects when in certain prefix. This is the expected behavior of this policy. If you remove this condition then the person can view all objects in your whole bucket. 
There is no way to let user navigate via gui since he isn't allowed to see the folders in the root.